# What is the naming convention or coding standard for categories in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I saw an example in *The iPhone Developer's Cookbook* that extends the UIDevice class using categories.

```
@interface UIDevice (Reachability)
   // some methods
@end
```

Typically classes are nouns and methods are verbs. From my point of view categories are similar to subclasses, so I would name the category a noun such as NetworkedUIDevice. How should the name of the category be determined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think a strict naming convention is established. Personally, I would go with something like `@interface UIDevice (ReachabilityAdditions)`.

More importantly, you should add a custom prefix to your category methods to avoid namespace conflicts. And this prefix should probably be included in the category name as well.